# How to get javax.comm API?

Tags: java, sms, javax.comm

I'd recently downloaded a project on `SMS` sending, but when I tries to compile the code it gives error on line `import javax.comm.*;`.

Can anybody tell me where to find `javax.comm` and where to place so that there will be no compilation error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Oracle Java Communications API Reference - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

Official 3.0 Download (Solarix, Linux) - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-misc-419423.html

Unofficial 2.0 Download (All): http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomm20jar.htm

Unofficial 2.0 Download (Windows installer) - http://kishor15389.blogspot.hk/2011/05/how-to-install-java-communications.html

In order to ensure there is no compilation error, place the file on your classpath when compiling (-cp command-line option, or check your IDE documentation).

Comment: I'd downloaded the .zip now there is a `comm.jar` file. Did I've to set the class path to this `comm.jar` file or I will extract the `comm.jar` file?

Comment: Just add the comm.jar to the classpath. Don't extract it.

Comment: so by putting `comm.jar` in classpath I don't  need have to change the code for `import javax.comm.*;`?

Comment: You have to import the classes you wish to use, along with adding comm.jar to the classpath.

Comment: @Ryan Schipper:there's only jar file but no API-documentation? How could I get that?  
And is there's no new link to download this API?

Comment: @RyanSchipper does this create dependencies on the machine that an application (which uses the Communication API) is going to be deployed?

Comment: @Saher an application that uses the Communication API will require an implementation of the Communication API (such as the linked download). And of course, Java Runtime Environment.

Comment: @DmitrySandalov Thanks - I have edited the post to include the java2s link.

Comment: Is that the most recent version? Is it discontinued? It looks like a download site that hoards jar files indiscriminately, that isn't maintained by the authors of javacomm.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus: The latest official version does not support Windows. I have added the official download link and rearranged the links.

Answer (score 20):

Use [**RXTX**](http://rxtx.qbang.org/).

On Debian install [librxtx-java](https://packages.debian.org/stable/java/librxtx-java) by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install librxtx-java
```

On Fedora or Enterprise Linux install [rxtx](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/rxtx) by typing:

```
sudo yum install rxtx
```

Comment: @MohammadFaisal RXTX is said to work on Windows, too.

Answer (score 2):

you can find Java Communications API 2.0 in below link

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomm20jar.htm

Answer (score 1):

Another Simple way i found in Netbeans right click on your project>libraris click add jar/folder add your comm.jar and you done.

if you dont have comm.jar download it from >>> http://llk.media.mit.edu/projects/picdev/software/javaxcomm.zip

Comment: is there no new link to download this API?

Comment: link dead ----------------

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu

```
 sudo apt-get install librxtx-java then
```

add RXTX jars to the project which are in

```
 usr/share/java
```

Comment: I have added the jar to the libraries, I cannot import javax.comm. So what now?