# The javax.comm package

Tags: location, package, javax.comm

I've searched far and wide for the javax.comm package, but I cannot find it anywhere. There is a download site for it at oracle, but it's just the API for it. Does anybody know where I can obtain the package? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is apparently lost in the Oracle nether regions.  You can find an answer that has a link to the old package here:

[How to get javax.comm API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562565/how-to-get-javax-comm-api)