# javax.comm in JDK 1.4.2

Tags: java, legacy, javax.comm

I've come across a legacy project which uses Java 1.4.2.
The project contains references to javax.comm for serial port communications.

I'm now trying to run this on java 7, and find that javax.comm is not included as part of the JDK.

What I can't find is confirmation that this was ever actually part of the standard JDK or JRE distribution back in the 1.4.2 days.

I'm just trying to find out if this worked because it used to be part of the standard distribution, or if someones did some fudging years ago to get it running.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javax.comm api was not part of the standard JDK and had to be installed separately. I can't find a current official download link from the [oracle page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7562613/139595) contains a [link to a zip file containing the windows version](http://llk.media.mit.edu/projects/picdev/software/javaxcomm.zip).

For linux you could look at [librxtx](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), version 2.0 should be API compatible.