# JAVA GUI : To send and receive data between an MSP430 and a Laptop

Tags: java, serial-port, communication, msp430

I have a requirement where I need to establish communication between Laptop and an MSP 430 device. The interface should be JAVA GUI.

I have experience with MSP430 and a little knowledge of JAVA.

Could any one suggest how to proceed for this or any resource available for this?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at Java COMM API. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562565/how-to-get-javax-comm-api

Answer (score 0):

> I need to establish communication between Laptop and an MSP 430 device. The interface should be JAVA GUI.

Please, distinguish GUI interface and communication interface. They are not the same.

For Java GUI you can start with [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). Have a `JButton` and `ActionListener` which would generate network message according to your device format and send it once button is clicked.

Comment: I tell you my complete requirement. There should be an interface on Laptop which should be able to communicate with my MSP430 device and should be able to fetch an array( sensor readings). The interface should have fields to enter info from the user. Now when the user hits 'generate' button, the info entered by the user and the readings fetched from the micro controller should be written to database. Also a file should be generated based on the info entered and should contain a graph based on the readings of micro-controller. I have experience with micro controller coding only.

Comment: @GauravK, so start learning `Swing` it would be your GUI API. For communication you might need to find some other GUI which deals which generating data, or if it simple communication use sockets and byte arrays in Java.