# Read, write or detect data through USB?

Tags: java

I am new to USB methods, so can anyone recommend any working USB lib along with the example code. Either how to read, write or detect USB anything.
Similar like http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wiki/jSSC_examples
for serial communication

Comment: Well I suppose you cant access USB directly... When it joins computer, it is added as "new drive" - for example at "j:/", and then you access it same as any other drive.

Comment: So there is no method to send/receive data?

Comment: Honestly I dont know :), but it makes sense that OS add USB as new driver and then you access it as driver (so you send/receive data by copying/creating files)

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe your probmlem indicates that you want to do serial communication to some device at the far end of the USB link.

most serial-based USB devices uses the standard USB interfaces to expose the remote device as a COM port (or serial device in UNIX), and then you can communicate using standard serial commands and API's.

From Java you will want to use the library [javax.comm](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) which appears to be the second favourite, or, more likely, the [rxtx library](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which appears to have strong support.

You should have a look at this question [How to get javax.comm API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562565/how-to-get-javax-comm-api)

Comment: Actually my full problem is
I am making a software that use another software to burn the data in the circuit and it is done through USB.
It do not show the USB as COM Port, So all i want to detect the USB is connected or not and whether the data is flowing in the USB or not.