# Where to download Java Communications API

Tags: java, java-communication-api

I want to build a Java application like callerID application.

But I can't find the link to download three files:

```
comm.jar
win32com.dll
javax.comm.properties
```

Some forums said: can be found at http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm.
But this link does not have them.

Where are these files available?

Comment: Related: [How to get javax.comm API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562565/how-to-get-javax-comm-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that all you need can be found in these 3 links :

[JavaComm](http://smslib.org/download/)

[win32com](http://www.4shared.com/file/TPRi1XRt/)

[Comm 2.0 prop](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomm20jar.htm)

Also if you encounter problems with javax.comm.properties have a look at this link 
[HERE](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1318406)

Comment: Thanks Maciej Cygan so much

Comment: The last link is good.

Comment: However, the JAR files found there are (comm-win32_all-2.0.1.jar etc) are actually ZIP files (containing JAR files and other stuff).