# How can i read data from parallel port by using java in windows?

Tags: java, parallel-port

Is it possible to read data from Parallel port?

I am sending data to Parallel port and read whatever data I am sending to that port, how can I do it by using java?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Java Communications API.

You will find usefull links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562565/how-to-get-javax-comm-api)